# Ubuntu getting auto shutdown/Crash

Tags: 16.10

I opened software center of Ubuntu 16.10, and there was notification  for an OS updates. I hit install.

After sometime my laptop got shutdown by itself. I turned it on Ubuntu login page appears and then it get shutdown/crash automatically.

I am not able to login or operate OS

Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem now. When I log in, the desktop session crashes and throws me right back into the login screen.

My solution:

- ctrl-alt-f1 to get to console.
- Log in and type "sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop"
- When finished, reboot or type "sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart"
- When login screen appears again, choose xubuntu-desktop instead of Ubuntu desktop, and everything should work again. Though you have to get used to a different desktop environment.